# How each video frame captured is represented in Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, video-processing

I am exploring Opencv VideoCapture.I am able to capture and display video.I tried to print each frame in console.Then i got a long numpy array.What is indicated by each number in that array?is it the RGB value of each pixel in that frame?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print len(frame)
    print frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code prints the following output to console

```
480
[[[119 115 116]
 [119 115 116]
 [118 113 117]
 ..., 
 [170 167 163]
 [170 168 162]
 [170 168 162]]

 [[121 115 121]
 [121 115 121]
 [119 113 119]
 ...,
```

what is each number indicates?How the grouping is done?

Comment: if you capture the video like this `ret, frame = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` then is `frame[y,x,color]` whereas color is defined as BGR in opencv

Comment: `"What is indicated by each number in that array?is it the RGB value of each pixel in that frame?"` - Yes. `"How the grouping is done?"` - Each row represents one pixel with each col for each of RGB channels. Each number represents intensity at each channel in `[0,255]` interval.

Comment: @nauer so in mycase Is 119 and 115 is corresponding y and x coordinates and 116 is the color?

Comment: @Divakar thank you,in the numpy array there are lists,lists of lists,lists of lists of lists.What is indicated by each list?

Comment: @user6745741 No. 119,115,116 is the blue, green and red value (from 0 to 255) on the coordiante [0,0], the next one is the color value on position [0,1]. [170 168 162]] is the last one in the row [0,x]. [[121 115 121] is the first color value in the 2nd row [1,0]. You have an array with 3 dimensions. The first two are the y and x coordinate the third are the 3 color values. If you convert it to a gray scale image you have only 2 dimensions.

Comment: @nauer Thank you.This solved my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by @nauer in the comments above:

The first element `[119,115,116]` corresponds to the Blue, Green and Red color components, respectively, of the pixel in the first row and column, i.e. pixel [0,0]. Each color component ranges from 0 to 255. The next element corresponds to the BGR color value for the next pixel in the same row, i.e. [0,1]. The element `[170 168 162]]` corresponds to the last BGR value in the first row [0,x]. `[[121 115 121]` is the first BGR color value in the 2nd row [1,0]. You have an array with 3 dimensions. The first two correspond to the y and x coordinates. The third one corresponds to the 3 BGR color components. Consequently, a grayscale image would have 2 dimensions only.